# How do I reformat text into a different pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

How can I program my code to change this pattern of BBBBB-AAA to 0AAABBBBB? I'm using asp.net, vb.net, and jQuery.

The format for a Canadian bank account routing number:

> A Canadian routing number displayed on a check needs to be reformatted
>   differently for electronic payments. If a check displays a routing
>   number as BBBBB-AAA (where AAA indicates the Financial Institution and
>   BBBBB is the branch), then the routing number must be changed to
>   0AAABBBBB to process the payment electronically. For example, if a
>   check from an account issued by the Bank of Montreal showed the
>   routing number 00011-001, then that number would need to be
>   reformatted to 000100011 for the payment to be electronically
>   processed.

I get data from the user here on my `.aspx` page:

```
<input id="txtBankCode" maxlength="9" required="required" />
```

And I grab the data here on my jQuery `.js` page:

```
var bankCode = $("#txtBankCode").val()
```

I need to rearrange `bankCode` to be the format `0AAABBBBB` instead of `BBBBB-AAA`. I am guessing some users will not type the dash while some users will. How can I do this?

Comment: Given the requirement of not relying on the dash in the number you can solve this with a regular expression. I'd suggest first figuring out if you want to do this in VB or JS (as both are possible) and then researching Regex

Answer (score 2):

Given that the hyphen is optional you can't rely on its presence in order to split the string. As such an alternative solution would be to use a regular expression to reorganise the string based on its input format. Try this:

Here's a JS solution:

```js
var bankCode = 'BBBBB-AAA';
bankCode = bankCode.replace(/^(\w{5})-?(\w{3})$/, '0$2$1');

console.log(bankCode);
```

And here's the same logic in VB:

```vb
Dim bankCode As String = "BBBBB-AAA"
bankCode = Regex.Replace(bankCode, "^(\w{5})-?(\w{3})$", "0$2$1")

Console.WriteLine(bankCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* I think I misunderstood your comment about the optional dash. A split won't work here, then, as it requires the dash to be present. So you'll need to first clean up the string by removing the dash if it's there, then use substring or regex to rearrange it:

```
bankCode = bankCode.replace(/-/g, '');
const first = bankCode.substring(0,5);
const second = bankCode.substring(5);
bankCode = `0${second}${first}`;
```

Comment: `I am guessing some users will not type the dash while some users will`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, I think I misread that as only needing the transformation if the user includes a dash. One sec, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function show() {
    var bankCode = $("#txtBankCode").val();
    console.log(bankCode.replace(/([a-zA-Z]{5})-?([a-z-A-Z]{3})/, `0$2$1`));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtBankCode" maxlength="9" required="required" />
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Show</button>
```